# Is there something like treeView_AfterSelect for listView too?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to put selected Items in a listView to an Array, I know when I use treeView you can use AfterSelect, is there something like this for listView too?

Comment: No.  Beware that SelectedIndexChanged runs multiple times, there is no "after", so be sure to not crash when nothing is selected and assume that the last one that fired is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ListView.SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Subscribe as below:

```
listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Event Handler:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```